# MySql wiped out

Tags: mysql, openshift

Hello and thanks in advance for your help.
I have been using play framework 1.2.5 on open shift to host an application. The framework is configured correctly on production mode and I don't use any Sql sentence to retrieve my data. I use the model methods to do this. Last morning (1 march 2014) I opened my site and found my database was completely wiped out. The tables were empty (maybe the framework re creating them) I can't think of a probable cause for this as play framework is supposed to be shielded against SQL injection. Can you suggest any ideas? Is there any way to have the data recovered by requesting the open shift team? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we do not have data recovery services avaiblable. Although for the future I would suggest taking a look at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/introducing-a-new-backup-cartridge to take your own backups of your app.